# Xamarin Forms Init crashes after adding FormsMaterial Init

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm attempting to add Xamarin.Forms Material Visual to my app. I'm following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual#initialize-material-visual) and after I add the Forms Material init, I get a crash in the Forms init. Here's the code...

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init();

    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Without `global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init();`, everything runs fine. When I add it, `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` crashes with an exception "System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException has been thrown" and "Could not find a property with name Priority". How does a line added after another cause an exception on the previous line? Anyone know what's going on?

Here's the stacktrace:

```
System.Reflection.CustomAttributeFormatException: Could not find a property with name Priority
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesInternal(System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,System.Type,bool)
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributesBase (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inheritedOnly) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:128
  at System.MonoCustomAttrs.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider obj, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/MonoCustomAttrs.cs:163
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes (System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeAssembly.cs:520
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll (System.Type[] attrTypes, Xamarin.Forms.ActivationFlags flags) [0x000a1] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:331
  at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Registrar.RegisterAll (System.Type[] attrTypes) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Registrar.cs:298
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init () [0x0009d] in <f0489d3941b24a20a5b9223b572ec7c0>:0
  at OSSM.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00001] in /Users/rob5408/Work/OSSM/OSSM.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:25
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
  at OSSM.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/rob5408/Work/OSSM/OSSM.iOS/Main.cs:18
```

Comment: Adding the Stacktrace might help i guess!!!

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: what's your Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material version,it works on my side.

Comment: Forms 4.3.0.991211, Material has the same version number, can that be right?

Comment: @rob5408 i run it on Forms 4.3.0.991211,it works,you could try to create a new empty project ,and add the Xamarin.Forms Material Visual nuget to test,see if it works

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Started a fresh project and it's also crashing there. Is there a step besides adding the dependency and adding the init?

Comment: There are no other steps. Add the nuget package and initialize it. by the way do you add the nuget in your form project ?

Comment: Yeah it's added, everything compiles fine. Is that what you mean by "by the way do you add the nuget in your form project"?

Comment: That's weird.I could not repeat it at all

Comment: Are you on a Mac? I'm not sure how that could be the cause, but I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: I am on a mac and had the exact same crash on iOS but with Forms Version 4.3.0709249. Updated to 4.3.0.991211 and the issue went away, although I also restarted Visual Studio in the process.

Comment: @JohnCummings thanks for the tip and for making not feel crazy. I'll give it another shot when they upgrade the library again.

Comment: @rob5408 Any update?

Comment: It was early in the project and so I convinced the client to go with React Native, probably not the update you’re looking for.